# Generating 1d array of shrinking ranges in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to generate a 1D array in numpy like this:

```
In [181]: np.concatenate((np.arange(1, 4), np.arange(2, 4), np.arange(3, 4)))
Out[181]: array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3])
```

On a larger scale, in pseudocode:

```
concatenate(1:n, 2:n, 3:n, ..., n:n)
```

Is there a vectorized way of doing this in numpy and/or pandas?

Comment: just curious, what's this for?

Comment: For some genetics data. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> np.triu_indices(4, 1)[1]
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3])
```

(As pointed out by @SaulloCastro, I didn't have to use all kinds of indexing into meshgrid magic like I did in the original, accepted answer.)

Comment: Easily fixable with `np.triu_indices(k, 1)`?

Comment: @larsmans I liked your solution... despite it needs more memory it gets orders of magnitude faster than the list comprehension for a high `k` value

Comment: @larsmans you could also play with `np.meshgrid(.., copy=False)` to avoid the high memory usage...

Comment: @SaulloCastro Looks like what I just posted is how `meshgrid` operates internally :)

Comment: @larsmans it comes out you only need `np.triu_indices(k, 1)[1]` to produce the same result...

Comment: @larsmans I mean that you only need `np.triu_indices(k, 1)[1]`, without the need of all the other functions to produce what the OP is looking for...

Comment: .. well, you're in good company.  I was working out the arithmetic to get the answer directly, but with floors and sqrts and aranges it's a lot less pretty than this.

Comment: `triu_indices` is appallingly slow in 1.8, should be much faster in 1.9, including some SIMD magic by Julian.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know a way to do it in a vectorized manner, but you could always generate it with something like this:

```
def createSweetRange(n):
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        for j in xrange(i, n):
            yield j
```